Extending a SQL WHERE clause based on a condition
I want to extend a WHERE condition based on the value of a field.  Trying this but t2.field3 is unable to be bound.  Is my syntax wrong?
SELECT * 
FROM table_one t1
JOIN table_two t2 on t1.field = t2.column
WHERE table_one.column2 = 'value'
    AND CASE WHEN t2.column3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'AND t2.column3= 8' END



You should be getting a syntax error from that, what is it? 2) What database and version are you using? 3) If your intent is to match t2.field3 when it is 8 or null, what about WHERE t1.field2 = "value" and (t2.field3 = 8 or t2.field3 is null)?


Note that tables have columns, not fields.

Also why is there an extra SeLECT shouldn't it be an AND? Why is "value" in double quotes?

Sorry I corrected that!

I don't think your simplified example is representing the problem you are trying to solve well since this is solvable with just: WHERE t1.column2 = 'value' AND t2.column3 = 8. If you wanted to be redundant by incorporating your superfluous t2.column3 IS NOT NULL logic, then just WHERE t1.column2 = 'value' and t2.column3 IS NOT NULL AND t2.column3 = 8. I doubt that is helpful info though. Please share your specific usecase and we can help you write it properly.

Since case when should return a boolean value there should be "then t2.column3=8". You are not adding some kind of text to your were statement.

CASE expressions are NOT like IF conditional branching, even when you remember the required END keyword, nor can they produce a boolean result. The expressions MUST result in a single value, when you can then compare with something else in a conditional expression. They do not create code to execute.
In this case (swidt?) you can remove the CASE expression completely with something like this:
WHERE t1.column2 = 'value'
    AND (t2.column3 IS NULL OR t2.column3 = 8)

which you could also write like this to remove the OR:
WHERE t1.column2 = 'value'
    AND coalesce(t2.column3,8) = 8


The shorter coalesce version is generally less efficient, as it can't use indexes at all. An OR can often use two unioned seeks.
